# How do I concatenate the data in column B based on the data from column A?

Tags: google-sheets, concatenate

I'd like to turn the image below:

[image: Spreadsheet]

into the following:

- A1: Yellow // B1: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
- A2: Blue // B2: The earliest known appearance of the phrase is from The Boston Journal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try:

```
=join(" ",FILTER(B:B,A:A=A1))
```

copied down to suit (I haven't because you data sample lacks consideration for those who rely on screen readers) then Copy/Paste special values only over the top and if say in ColumnC then:

```
 =unique(C:C)
```

Copy/Paste special values only over the top again and delete surplus.